# Could not access parent scope in directive, it's read-only on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all, I find out I couldn't change the value in `directive`

So I have to use `$scope.$applyAsync` to modify the quick_search_ctrl controller's scope,

and use `$scope.$watch` to enable the 2 way binding.

I'm new to Angular.js, 
I think to put the update logic in directive is strange and not intuitive
How could I put the logic in  `quick_search_ctrl`?
Why could not I just modify the value by `$scope.slider_status.from`, instead, I need to wrapper the actions in applyAsync ?

Did I do any thing wrong about the directive and controller ?

Thanks

## main.js

```
var quick_search_app = angular.module('quick_search_app', ["highcharts-ng"]);
```

## quick_search_ctrl.js

```
quick_search_app.controller('quick_search_ctrl',
  ...
  $scope.slider_status = {from: "test"};
});
```

## ionslider.js

```
quick_search_app.directive('ionslider',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'AE',
        scope: false,
        controller: 'quick_search_ctrl',
        link:function($scope, $element){
            $($element).ionRangeSlider({
                    onChange: function(slider) {
                        $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
                            $scope.slider_status.from = slider.from;
                        });
                        $scope.$watch('slider_status', function() {
                            // change the parent's model here
                        });
                    }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `true` as third param in `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('slider_status', function() {
    // change the parent's model here
}, true);
```

Because you try to watch object you need `deep` watch.
See more about it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope